# How to sort by order of the weekdays (as in a calendar week) instead of alphabetical order (in C#)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I cannot work out how to sort the output from a query in an XML file in isolated storage by the day which is a value in the xml file.

By this I mean it will sort by the first letter(s) of the day, so it will return Friday as the first one (because of the "F" in it). But that is not what I want, instead they should be sorted by the order of the weekdays, i.e. monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday.

Is there any way I can convert a string which contains the day in text eg. "monday" to a DateTime to sort by?

The code I am using is like so:

```
 let obv = (string)query.Element("day")
 orderby obv 
 select new obv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by the value's index in the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateFormat.DayNames` array:

```
var daynames = Array.ConvertAll(
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateFormat.DayNames,
    d => d.ToUpperInvariant()
);

from ...
let obv = (string)query.Element("day")
orderby Array.IndexOf(daynames, obv.ToUpperInvariant())
select new obv
```

Comment: The OP needs to sort by order of the days, not by the alphabetical order.

Comment: @Oded: I'm well aware of that.  That's what `IndexOf` does.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I'm not sure whether WP7 supports Array.ConvertAll. Is there a namespace i should be adding?

Comment: @Jamie: That's part of the core `System.Array` class.  It will work _anywhere_.

Comment: @SLaks - 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertAll'

Comment: Apparently, `Array.ConvertAll` doesn't exist in Silverlight.  You can replace it with LINQ or a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to sort by an arbitrary day of the week:

```
public class DayOfWeekComparer : IComparer<DayOfWeek>
{
    public static int Rank(DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek, DayOfWeek x)
    {
        return (int)x + (x < firstDayOfWeek ? 7 : 0);
    }

    public static int Compare(DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek, DayOfWeek x, DayOfWeek y)
    {
        return Rank(firstDayOfWeek, x).CompareTo(Rank(firstDayOfWeek, y));
    }

    DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek;

    public DayOfWeekComparer(DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
    {
        this.firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek;
    }

    public int Compare(DayOfWeek x, DayOfWeek y)
    {
        return DayOfWeekComparer.Compare(this.firstDayOfWeek, x, y);
    }
}
```