# How to sort an array of week days so that they appear as in a calendar week (in C#)?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file being read into a `string[]` containing the days Monday to Friday, but in a random order. I want to sort them so they appear as they do in a calendar week.

I've tried `Array.Sort()` and `Array.Reverse()` but they don't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do they contain strings, or actual DateTime objects?

Comment: Just Strings. E.g. the word 'Monday' or 'Friday', etc.

Comment: Ok.   Well the problem is that the sorting methods are treating them as just strings, so they are sorted alphabetically.  You need to turn them into actual days of the week (which is an enum ( a number)).  Then the sorts will work correctly.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I'm quite new to programming. Sorry.

Comment: Take a look here about how to convert all elements in an array: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.100).aspx you could use this to convert to days of the week.

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484127/sort-by-day-of-week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sort it by the corresponding value of enum `DayOfWeek` of your string, then return it back to a string.

```
string [] initialArray = {"Friday", "Monday", ... } ; 

string [] sortedArray = initialArray.OrderBy(s => Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), s)).ToArray() ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is that the sorting methods are treating them as just strings, so they are sorted alphabetically (the default comparison for strings). You need to [turn them into actual days of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713366/c-datetime-dayofweek-to-string-comparison/13713397#13713397) (which is an enum ( a number)).

To convert into a `DayOfWeek` enum:

```
public static DayOfWeek ToDayOfWeek(string str) {
        return (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), str);
}
```

Then you can just sort them using the built-in functions.

I like LINQ:

```
String[] weekdayArray = {"Monday", "Saturday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Friday"};
var daysOfWeek = weekdayArray
    .Select(str => ToDayOfWeek(str))
    .OrderBy(dow => dow);
```

Here is a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pfW2HT).

Comment: Might as well make `ToDayOfWeek` a `DateTime` extension.

Comment: I did actually make it an extension (to `String`) in the .NET Fiddle.  But explaining extension methods is more than I want to do.